# Looking for a step by step guide to URL re-writing with mod_rewrite and other methods

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for step by step resource about how to rewrite URLs and have a few specific questions.

I've read the documentation on `mod_rewrite` in Apache, but I still find myself a little lost.

1. If I have `example.com/products.html`, can I change this to appear as `example.com/products`? For that to happen, do I make all of my links point to `/products` and then have a rewrite rule that directs `/products` to `/products.html`?  Or is it the other way around?
2. Also, for PHP forms, I've noticed that I can't have a form action that points to a directory: for example, it requires `/mail/index.php` instead of just `/mail`.

Can `mod_rewrite` fix this too?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite can do both things. Relevant: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/q/214512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article on Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/) or [Pekka's link shared in the comments above](https://serverfault.com/q/214512) should help you but there are [quite a few others out there](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=heb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&site=webhp&source=hp&q=mod_rewrite%20step%20by%20step%20guide&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&ix=heb&ion=1&ix=heb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=955&ix=heb&ion=1).